# UR5 - Gazebo Joint Position controller

Tags: ros, gazebo, manipulator, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I need to **simulate a velocity control** of a UR5 robot in Gazebo + ROS. But current packages of UR only has **a joint trajectory controller,** But I want to control individual joint velocities over time.
How can I do this using existing controller ?
or If I create **joint position controllers** how can I find pid gains that will do the simulation correctly ?

Are any other robot manipulator model with tuned position controllers for Gazebo simulation ?

Your help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225420/ur5---gazebo-joint-position-controller/) by [dinesh_sl](https://answers.ros.org/users/18136/dinesh_sl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The modern drivers implement a velocity controller: https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver

---

Originally posted by [claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/26742/claudio/) with karma: 16 on 2016-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0